# How to keep a list output all on one line w/ out getting the next line of code included

Tags: python

I have prompts to ask the user for 5 pieces of info that in turn append them to a list, then prints that list out for them to see. I want the list to all fit on one line and then ask the user for new input to generate a new list. But instead the new input gets added on to the end of the list.

So far I've tried looking up how to create a new line w/ the \n but that doesn't seem to be working.

Using MS VS Code for the IDE and getting the squiggly lines when I try putting in \n after the section of code that says end=' ' or before the next user input as \n employeeName_2 = str(input('Name: '))

```
# user input
employeeName_1 = str(input('Name: '))
employeeSSN_1 = str(input('SSN: '))
employeePhone_1 = str(input('Phone: '))
employeeEmail_1 = str(input('Email: '))
employeeSalary_1 = str(input('Salary: '))

# list 1 append
emp_list_1.append(employeeName_1)
emp_list_1.append(employeeSSN_1)
emp_list_1.append(employeePhone_1)
emp_list_1.append(employeeEmail_1)
emp_list_1.append(employeeSalary_1)

for count1 in range(0, len(emp_list_1)):
    print(emp_list_1[count1], end=' ')

# user input for list 2
employeeName_2 = str(input('Name: '))
```

expecting the output to look like this:
Mike Smith 123121234 (111)222-3333 mike@gmail.com $6000

Instead getting this:
Mike Smith 123121234 (111)222-3333 mike@gmail.com $6000 Name:

Comment: Why not a `print()` outside the loop but just before `employeeName_2 = str(input('Name: '))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to put the `\n` in the string.

```
employeeName_2 = str(input('\nName: '))
```

Another option would be an empty print statement.

```
print()
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I will be using the empty print statement as I can copy and past that with out altering a bunch of the code I already have typed in a faster manner. I will however remember this for future reference. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

To print a list in one line even if the list don't contains `str` only

```py
    # to print your list in one line this will work even when your list don't contains str
    # if you are sure it's all str print(' '.join(emp_list_1))
    print(*emp_list_1, sep=' ')
```

And to ask for information don't repeat your self here try this:

```py
    employee_list = []
    for i in range(2):  # number of employee == 2 for testing, make it a variable
        employee = []
        for attribute in ['Name', 'SSN', 'Phone', 'Email', 'Salary']:
             employee.append(str(input(f'{attribute}: ')))
        print(f'Employee {i} : ', ' '.join(employee))  # print employee information
        employee_list.append(employee)

    # and when you finish all employee are here
    print(employee_list)
```

Comment: I think you are repeating your code a lot, checkout my edits it will help you

Comment: Thank you for the different types of ways I could edit this to get a new line. With my current build and time, I'll be using the empty print statement, but a like the sep=' ' as a more formal way to get it done also. Props!

Comment: Okay but you should follow The DRY principle (don't repeat your self) Hope you take a look at my edits and see how it can be done with less coding.

Comment: Appreciate the extra help. I'm very new to coding and am just using what I have learned so far. I'm wondering how I can have this create 5 separate lists that can then be pulled by user choice later? I have another thread with that question.

Comment: I noticed that the input expression uses a dictionary bracket, wasn't aware that could be put in like that, also wondering what the (f' is in reference to? Apologies on all the questions, I need to be able to break down all of the parts of the code to better understand how  and where its used.

Comment: `f` is used for literal string formation. it can be done like this too:  `'{}'.format('some_value')` or `'{some_value}'.format(some_value='some_value')` or `'{some_value}'.format({'some_value': 'some_value'})`. and good luck with your programming career don't forget to read books when you done with basics you will find a lot of thing that you will learn in years by self.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
for count1 in range(0, len(emp_list_1)):
    print(emp_list_1[count1], end=' ')
```

try

```
print(' '.join(emp_list_1))
```

print() normally adds a newline character after the output. When you use `end=' '` as parameter in print() it adds a whitespace instead. This is why the next print() or input() is written in the same line.

Also you don't need to use str() to cast the result from input(). Because input() already returns a string.

Comment: Hi, I appreciate the help. All of these comments will be helpful at one time or another as I begin my programming career. Thanks again.